# Is publishing a package to npm necessary when a file that is ignored by npm is changed and published to GitHub?

Tags: github, npm, semantic-versioning

The project contains a test folder that is ignored by npm but is not ignored by GitHub. When a change occurs in a file under the test folder, should it be also published to npm in order to keep versions matching? Also, in that case, semantic versioning should be increased while there is no change for npm.

---

Assume that there is a repo in GitHub which has a test folder that is ignored by npm. It also has the package.json file which is tracking version number inside the repo.

Q1. When a change occurred in a file under the test folder, should the patch version number be increased?

Q2. Somehow (if the answer of Q1 is yes, as it is in the first question but there might be other similar cases), when a minor version increase happened in the package.json file, but nothing is changed in the files on npm side, what should be done?

Comment: Why do you think you *would* need to publish a version that contains no actual changes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the best practice says, when you have a GitHub repo and an npm repo for the same package, the versions of the repos should be in sync. If I only publish a version in GitHub (since there is an actual change), then the versions will not be in sync.

Comment: I don't know where you heard that, but it's not true. You can choose which commits you want to publish as versions of the package - it's common to use tags for this, for example.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this thread, I think the question is quite clear.  I would not vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last edit first:

The short answer to your question is no.  The repo will march on ahead of whatever is published in your feeds until you cut a new release.

---

So the problem here is that you apparently track version numbers either in a file in your repo, or in the commit labels/tags.  Don't do that, it's pointless.  I know it's a very common practice (I've made that mistake myself), but it is born out of lazy thinking.  Repo's are not the right kind of database to track this sort of thing.  Only published packages need to have any kind of version label on them.  The data-flow should be from repo => build system => package repository.  The arrows should never be reversed.

When you apply that rule, your question is moot.  Your test content is a separate package feed from your release content (NPM).  It already has repo hashes, that are unique, unambiguous and immutable.  Those hashes should flow to the build system, then to the package feed/repository system.

---

There is always a difference in the release date/time stamps between test and product development.  Product releases always lag test releases.  The purpose of a particular version of the test suite, is to validate a product release.  So you should always see test suite `X.Y.Z+repoHashN`, precede product version `X.Y.Z+repoHashN`.  Note that the values of X, Y and Z for test and product, need not have the same values (a product patch, might be the result of fixing known bug surfaced by the test suite), but there should always be a 'repoHashN' that uniquely matches a test version triple and product version triple.

---

You produce two products, an app and a test suite, from the same repo, and most of the tooling out there tracks a version per branch that is applied to all packages produced from that branch.  I can't directly address any specific NPM behavioral issues, I don't use it enough, but I am fairly sure you are not encountering a bug, rather you are most likely using it incorrectly.

Because your two products develop on separate cadences, you should consider maintaining a test branch for versioning test code.  There's a seemingly endless variety of possibilities for your workflows here.

I recommend using a master or main branch for the tip of all development. Always cut prerelease `(-<#>+master.<repoHash>)` versions from this branch, and you might as well only ever bump either the patch number or the prerelease tag number (NPM supports either scenario).  Then, when you are ready to cut a release, you fork master or main into a release branch (named after the target major.minor version) and cut only release packages out of that branch.  Because your test code version is not relevant to the release package version, you don't need to track that specifically, it's always updated when you merge from main/master or test/dev branches to cut the next patch level release.  The patch level of the release branch only gets bumped when you are ready to release it to the public.

Do test development in a test branch to hide the churn that doesn't need to show up in the master/main history.  A dozen "BUG:### WIP" entries aren't needed there so you squash merge from test to master or main. Same thing holds for product code development.  Do that in a Dev branch.  Test and dev branches should only ever cut packages with something like a `-<#>+<devNam>.<repoHash>` tag on them and only published to private feeds.

The purpose of master/main branch is to provide frequent (at least daily) build and test cycles that include merged content from test and dev branches.  This is where you maintain ground truth.  At any given time you should be able to safely fork a new branch from here and count on it to build a product that meets your quality specs. This allows you the freedom to cut release branches at whatever cadence you need, independent of the current state of the test or dev branches.  Test and dev, should attempt to merge their work into master or main, at least daily, and immediately fix any merge conflicts or build failures.

In the case where test == dev, you can combine them into a single branch.  Generally, each developer will have many branches in progress, for independent work on various tasks.  Having them merge directly to main or master is a valid workflow and even considered a best practice in many shops.  Sometimes, too many cooks in the kitchen however, can cause problems, and when you find your dev's are spending too much time resolving merge conflicts with master or main. You'll want separate branches for different lines of effort, for them to stage their work into, before taking it to master.  Then flow into master or main isn't quite so random, and will be easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To make my question more clear, see the package https://github.com/thedolphinos/really. It has a test folder that is ignored by npm. It also has package.json which is tracking version number inside the repo, as you stated in your answer. When I fix a bug in a test suite, I should (as far as I know I should) increase the patch version number(the Z in X.Y.Z). Now, since the fix caused a change in the package.json file, npm release is needed. But it seems nothing is changed on the npm side. Did I make myself a bit more clear? In this case, what should I do?

Comment: The first step is always to [edit] your post with the clarifications.  That may improve the quality enough to get a decent answer.  It will also allow any down-voters to change their vote if they find it has improved enough.  It sounds to me like you are running into the issue I described in my answer.  I'll add additional information to my answer...

Comment: I agree that tracking version numbers in a file in the repo is not the best practice. However, while publishing a Node.js package, you need to have a package.json file which tracks version numbers as I said before.

Comment: You could generate package.json files at build time.  But that's a whole other topic we need not get into here.

Comment: I know that package.json can be generated during build phase however this not related to package publishing. Even you can generate it, you have to include it while publishing.

Comment: See my last edit to the answer.  It gives you some options to work around the problem.

Comment: By the way I got your point. Separate branch for tests will solve the problem in that case. Thanks for the clarification. I see that is the most convenient use. What is your opinion when using the same branch as it is in my case?